# Show only the cards i need in Jinja2/Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i have problem with displaying html cards, but only for the songs i want to "filter".
I have songs in database and i want only to get the songs' artists i have in my javascript array.

```html
{% for song in songs %}

                    <script>
                        var song_filename = "../static/uploads/{{ song.filename }}";
                        var song_name = "{{song.name}}";
                        var song_artist = "{{song.artist_name}}";
                        var song_genre = "{{song.genre}}";

                        if(fY.includes(song_artist))
                        {
                            js_songs.push(song_filename);
                            js_songs_name.push(song_name);
                            js_songs_artists.push(song_artist);
                            js_songs_genre.push(song_genre);
                            console.log("[DEBUG] Added - " + song_name + " - " + song_artist);
                        }
                    </script>   

                            <div class="card" id="song-card">
                                <div class="card-body flex-row flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 my-auto">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col mx-auto">
                                            <h4>{{ song.name }}</h4>
                                            <div class="dropleft"><button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle float-right" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" style="background: #4ecca3;border-style: none;">Add to playlist</button>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right float-left"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Playlist 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Playlist 2</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Playlist 3</a></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">{{ song.artist_name }}</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        <label for="genre">{{ song.genre }}</label>
                                    </p>

                                    <button class="btn btn-primary play-pause" onclick="loadTrack({{loop.index}} - 1) ; playTrack()" type="button" style="background: #191414;border-style: none;">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-play">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.804 8L5 4.633v6.734L10.804 8zm.792-.696a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.392l-6.363 3.692C4.713 12.69 4 12.345 4 11.692V4.308c0-.653.713-.998 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    
                                    <audio src="../static/uploads/{{song.filename}}" id="song"></audio>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

So i have this code. Songs are songs from database. fY is the js array. I want to show the card div only if fY.includes(song_artist).

Comment: Your question/issue is not clear. Can you restate?

Comment: @NoCommandLine okay. So i want to display the bootstrap card, but only when fY.includes(song_artist). I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Where is ``fy``` coming from? If it's coming from the same backend as ```songs```, then it makes more sense to do the processing at the backend and just add an attribute to a song that lets you know if it should be displayed or not. This does away with the javascript call you are making within your ```for loop```

Comment: @NoCommandLine not, it's taking the songs from the backend and filter it in js file.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does not have the card display dependent on the javascript filtering i.e. your display of cards is entirely outside the javascript logic.

Some approaches to solving your problem are

1. Keep your code as is but remove the embedded Javascript. If you're using Bootstrap, add a class of `collapse` to each card (this makes the card hidden) else just use `display:none`. Have Javascript code which runs at the end of `page load` to loop through all the cards, check if a song's artist is included in `fy`. If it is, then you remove the `collapse`  or `display:none`from the card which then makes the card visible.
2. use an Ajax call to return your songs as JSON, filter them using your `fy` array and then use Javascript to loop and display the cards
3. See if you can pass the `fy` array to the backend, then filter the songs in the backend and only return the filtered results to the UI. This way you can still use Jinja to display the results but you are only displaying the already filtered results

Comment: Okay, but how i can show bs cards with js loop?

Comment: You can use a template like mustache